# Padding number with 0s before doing a insert into a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert a value into this database field but it needs to be padded with leading 0s if this number has less than 9 digits, as an example, `12345` should be converted to `000012345` before inserting it into the database. I am trying this, but it's not working, I can not use stored procedure, is it possible?

```
insert into my_table (right('00000000' + cast(account as char(8)), 8)) values ('12345')
```

Comment: This sounds like something you should be able to handle on the display layer, instead of storing a number as a string in the database. Is there a reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: What **datatype** is that column you want to store into? A numerical column just stores the **numerical value** - no leading zeroes (those are pointless, in terms of numerical value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. You have the expression (i.e. the CAST and RIGHT functions) in the column name specification area instead of the value area
2. You are casting to a right-padded text field (i.e. CHAR) of 8 characters (left 5 chars are 12345 and 3 more spaces to the right) and then adding the zeros to the left before grabbing the 8 right-most characters.  The right-most 8 just happen to be 12345 + 3 spaces ;-).  You should use VARCHAR instead.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (Account)  
VALUES (RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(12345 AS VARCHAR(8)), 8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [STR()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) to convert numbers to right-justified strings.  Procedures that use CONVERT(varchar(8),...) can't be parameterized because varchar(@size) is invalid.

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(12345,8),' ','0')
```